# jQuery validating dynamically created reCaptcha forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am validating forms using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.brochure_form').validate();
});
```

I currently have invisible recaptcha being dynamically created with this (this works without validation).

```
function onloadCallback() {
    var count = 1;

    $(".g-recaptcha").each(function() {
        var object = $(this);
        var theid = object.attr('id');      
        var widgetID = "recaptcha_" + count;
        grecaptcha.render("recaptcha_" + count, {
            "sitekey" : "SITEKEY",
            "callback" : function(token) {


                object.parents('form').find(".g-recaptcha-response").val(token);

                // VALIDATE HERE
                if(object.parents('form').valid() == true){
                    object.parents('form').submit();
                } else {
                    grecaptcha.reset(widgetID);

                };
            }
        });
        count++;

    });
}
```

At the minute this is how it works;

1. Form validates with reCaptcha
2. Form runs jQuery validate
3. Submits

The issue is if form validates #1 and then fails on #2 I need to reset reCaptcha to do it again (this is where I am struggling, as I can't pass widgetID correctly - if I leave this blank it works for the first form only)

My ideal scenario would be to switch #1 and #2 but I couldn't get this working either.

Also, the above currently returns

```
Uncaught (in promise) null
```

Here's HTML for reference (Stripped out all fields as it's quite a big form)

```
<form id="form--brochure1" class="brochure_form " action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha_1" data-badge="inline">
</form>

<form id="form--brochure2" class="brochure_form " action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha_2" data-badge="inline">
</form>
```

The page just refreshes on submit but I am doing server-side validation as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

$secretKey = 'SECRETKEY';
$response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$reCaptchaValidationUrl = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteIp");
$result = json_decode($reCaptchaValidationUrl, TRUE);


  if($result['success'] == 1) {
     // EMAIL SENT, DATABASE UPDATED ETC HERE
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is the HTML markup?  Does your form submit refresh the page?  If so, then any previous captcha result is invalid.  What you seek is no trivial task.  I've ended up using PHP on the server to check the captcha and jQuery Validate's `remote` method OR `submitHandler` callback to dynamically check the captcha.

Comment: @Sparky thanks for that and the link. I've updated my question to included more details. I'll check out the link you sent but if you have any more insight - thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you're already doing captcha on the server, then you need to use the `submitHandler` or the `remote` method of the jQuery Validate plugin for proper integration.  `remote` method is better because the captcha box will be validated the same as any other field.